# How do I correct a "const mismatch in out variable"?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

So I'm currently writing code to access a player's uniqueNetId using:

```
Class'GameEngine'.static.GetOnlineSubsystem().UniqueNetIdToString(
        OnlineSubsystemSteamworks(Class'GameEngine'.static.GetOnlineSubsystem()).LoggedInPlayerId.Uid);
```

But that leads to this:

```
Error, Call to 'UniqueNetIdToString', parameter 1: Const mismatch in Out variable
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually a const mismatch. The function is expecting a struct and you are passing in a member of the struct instead. Try removing the `.Uid`, i.e.:

```
Class'GameEngine'.static.GetOnlineSubsystem().UniqueNetIdToString(
        OnlineSubsystemSteamworks(Class'GameEngine'.static.GetOnlineSubsystem()).LoggedInPlayerId);
```